# Selecting the secondary preceding element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<tr class="main"></tr>
<tr class="emails-details">
     <button>some button</button>
</tr>
<tr class="main"></tr>
<tr class="emails-details">
     <button>some button</button>
</tr>
<tr class="main"></tr>
<tr class="emails-details">
     <button>some button</button>
</tr>
```

I want to select the previous tr.main after clicking a button but cannot figure out how to get to the right previous elemetn using .prev(), .prevAll(), or .prevUntil()

```
$(function() {
     $('.dropdown-image').click(function() {
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().prev($("tr:nth-of-type(1)")).children().css('border-bottom-color', '#a3d0dd');
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().prevUntil('.main').children().css('border-bottom-color', '#a3d0dd');
     });
});
```

Iv got the first row sorted because it doesnt have a row of tr.emails-detials after it but i need to change the border-bottom-color of the row above, as seen below the blue border is missing from the selected row.

[image]

Comment: `$(this).closest('tr').prev('.main')`

Comment: Whenever you're doing `.parent().parent().parent() .... ` you're doing something wrong !

Comment: This should be pretty easy to solve, but I just want to ask a question real quick. Can you change the markup HTML?  It would make more sense to make the email details be the tbody of an embeded table in your individual rows.

Comment: Didn't know that jQuery method but wouldn't `$(this).closest('tr.main')` work here ?

Comment: That's not how [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) works.  It's the closest ancestor, so you will need to use `.prev` with `.closest`

Comment: @adeneo this didn't seem to work, but how do you suggest i shorten my .parent().parent() etc...

Comment: @JosephMarikle yes this would make sense haha i may have to think of changing it all up if i cant get it to work, im only new with this and am just trying to teach myself as i go :)

Answer (score 0):

Well i solved my problem using

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().prev('tr').prev('.main').children().css('border-bottom-color', '#a3d0dd');
```

i know someone will comment about the .parent().parent() and .prev().prev() etc but problem solved for now.